# Wich entropy is higher: that of a living tree or a house built from this tree?

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy

Consider a big tree (in it's "best" years from the viewpoint of carpenters) standing in a forest, with no leaves in it, because it's wintertime. It's clearly not a [closed "system"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermodynamic_system) because there is a lot of interaction with its surroundings (by means of the roots, leaves, heat exchange, etc.). Then we take the whole tree out of the ground and let it die (so the interaction with its surroundings becomes less, though you don't have to wait too long, for otherwise the rotting process will get the overhand, and the interaction with its environment will become bigger) an and use the whole tree (including the roots) to make a wooden house. The tree is big enough to make a house to comfortably live in and is filled with wooden furniture, also made from the tree.

During the construction of the house some parts of the tree will be thrown away, but let's assume that this part is negligible. It is also clear that the house we've constructed out of the tree is not a closed system. But if we consider the house when it's just finished, the house didn't have much time to interact with the environment. Of course, we have to use all kinds of (hand driven or energy powered) machines (though we can the biggest part manually too, with the help of fewer tools, which makes the construction time longer, so there will be less pollution caused by energy supplied tools).

What can we say about the [entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy) (a [state variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_variable)) of the tree compared with the entropy of the tree after it's been taken out of the ground? At first sight, it looks (but looks can deceive) like the house has a much more ordered structure than the tree, so you would think that the house has smaller entropy as the house. And if we also take all **our** interactions with the tree (cutting it in smaller pieces of wood, in these days probably with the aid of fossil fuels-driven tools) into account, what can we say about the overall entropy of the tree and the house?

It's a rather complex question I guess, but it can be answered by main-stream physics.

Comment: The order that appears to the human eye, e.g. as arising from constructing a house, has no bearing on the thermodynamic entropy unless the construction also changes any of the thermodynamic state functions of the wood (which it would, e.g. the strain would modify the enthalpy).

Comment: Seconded. Any entropy change from positioning the wood in various ways is absolutely infinitesimal relative to the entropy change from the variation of thermodynamic intensive variables such as the temperature and water content, for example. Be careful not to overextend the "messy room" analogy of entropy.

Comment: The ordering business is a sloppy way of talking of statistical entropy: the number of microstates . A crystal, crystalizing out of a solution has lower entropy because of less microstates, at the expense of raising the entropy of the solution. Living organisms in a larger system have less microstates, because the DNA for example constrains the number of microstates from what the free atoms and molecules could attain. Once dead, the microstates freeze at the state they were.  The entropy should be more or less the same .     en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(statistical_thermodynamics) –

Comment: @annav I don't think that's entirely true, since dead organisms typically decay. When DNA and other large biomolecules break down, typically they produce simpler molecules that reduce the constraints on individual atoms' motion, so the entropy should increase, all other things being equal.

Comment: I think that a comment by J. Sethna in his book is appropriate here:  "There are interesting examples of systems that appear to develop more order as their entropy (and temperature) rises. These are systems where adding order of one, visible type (say crystalline or orientational order) allows increased disorder of another type (say, vibrational disorder). Entropy is a precise measure of disorder, but is not the only possible or useful measure." - in "Entropy, Order Parameters, and Complexity" by J. Sethna.

Comment: What is your proof this can be answered by main-stream physics?  Entropy is  at a microscopic level.

Comment: @probably_someone-You're absolutely right. But I wrote **though you don't have to wait too long, for otherwise, the rotting process will get the overhand**.

Comment: @Chemomechanics-But it takes a lot of energy to transform the tree into a house with wooden furniture. This energy doesn't change the wood's temperature. Doesn't that mean that the entropy of the house is becoming less (than that of the tree)?

Comment: @annav-**more or less** is a rather sloppy way of answering this question. It's **more** or **less**.

Comment: @Paparazzi-I can ask just as well: what is your proof that it can't?

Comment: This seems like a Bio-101 sort of question.  Typically, the story's that living things maintain a low-entropy state by taking in energy.  Seems like the fuller story'll tend to be more complex.

Comment: @descheleschilder I am not the one making the assertion.

Comment: True. But why should I be obliged to prove my assumption just because you ask? I can see no reason why mainstream-physics can't solve this problem, even though I have no proof of this. It seems just pretty obvious to me. And **how** could I prove this? What kind of non-mainstream physics did you have in mind?

Comment: I think somebody isn't so happy with one of my comments...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would definitely say that the house has less entropy than the tree. First, note that there are two processes that mainly contribute to change of entropy:

1. The tree dies, which is pretty irreversible (entropy grows at the cell scale, because cells are ordered structures when they are alive while the atomic structure remains similar because you don't let the tree rot). For this part you can actually approximate the tree as being a closed system.
2. Processing the tree to make the house and furniture. After reading about how the process of making wood works, I would say that you have to cut and throw away a substantial part of the initial tree (without producing any change on its atomic structure), so that the entropy of the remaining part is notably less than the initial one.

All the other processes involved (such as the form of the furniture and house, or the placement of these) are subleading.

Thus, accepting that the house has less entropy than the tree, there is a lot of entropy generated in the second process above, so that the net entropy of house + woodcuter + rest of the tree (useless to make the house) + heat is bigger than the intial entropy of the tree.

Comment: Doesn't the **making** of the house (especially with tools that are driven by non-human energy, like electricity or fossil fuels) create a considerable amount of entropy in the surroundings of the tree?